# Linux socket transfer is adding extra zero padding

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, padding

While I am trying to send data from Linux Client to Server over TCP I see extra zeros being added to the data. Can anyone please let me know why am I getting those additional zeroes? Please see below for the data packet format.

```
#define INT32 int32_t
#define UCHAR unsigned char
#define UINT8 u_int8_t

typedef struct cstruct_t {
    UINT8           typ;
    UINT8           l;
    unsigned char   buf[20];
} cksum_t;

cstruct_t       cs; 
INT32           fnlength;
```

Comment: "I see extra zeros being added to the data"  In what way did you *see* the extra zeros?

Comment: Your structure is 22 bytes long without padding -- your compiler is simply adding 2 extra padding bytes to make it an even 4-byte length

Comment: Thanks for the update @Soren. But we would need a workaround to send 22 bytes as the server will not accept if the data size varies.

Comment: @nodakai we are viewing it using wireshark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we dint want to add additional zeroes to make it 4-byte long as mentioned by @Soren we used

`#pragma pack(push, 1)`

`#pragma pack(pop)`

This worked perfectly for us.

Comment: Dear @Namitha Can you help me to add padding data for this data type ```std::vector<uint8_t> Data = {0x34, 0x00, 0x24, 0xFD, 0xC0, 0x7E, 0x2E, 0x20, 0x00};``` , I want to add 4 ```0x00``` after Data

Answer (score 2):

> Linux socket transfer is adding extra zero padding

No it certainly is not. You probably aren't reading it correctly. London to a brick you are ignoring the value returned by `recv()`.

But you shouldn't be using a `struct` as a network protocol in the first place.